# How to generate the resource file (EN) for current form with a lot of controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, localization

Currently, I have a form named 'Form1' with 3 Lables, 3 Textboxs, 1 GridView with 10 columns.

I tried to use 'Localizable' attribute and set Language to English. But I have to go one-by-one control, change its text, and save, then the resource file will generate.

It makes me spend more time to apply for all controls.
Is there any way to add the resource file with fully controls more easier? We don't need to update the text for each control.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer for your question is NO. There is no shortcut for this task. However, you should do it only for Forms (initially). VS creates the resource file and generate a few lines of codes when you set the `Localizable` property `true` just for the Form. Then you can go to the designer code and add the `Localizable` property for the rest of the controls if required.